# Syncing gifs to tempo of music results in shorter duration than expected

Tags: python, audio, gif

I'm attempting to sync a gif to the beat of music playing on Spotify, but I'm encountering a speed issue while doing so. I must be going crazy because I can't find a reason as to why this isn't working. Below is my methodology:

- Take initial BPM (ex: 150) and find the Beats/Second (`BPS`)

  - `BPS = BPM / 60`
- Find the Seconds/Beat (`SPB`) from the Beats/Second (`BPS`)

  - `SPB = 1 / BPS`
- Find the Seconds/Loop (`SPL`) by multiplying by the number of Beats/Loop (`BPL`) of the .gif

  - `SPL = SPB * BPL`
- Convert Seconds/Loop (`SPL`) to Milliseconds/Loop (`MSPL`)

  - `MSPL = SPL * 1000`
- Divide the Milliseconds/Loop (`MSPL`) by the number of frames (`num_frames`) in the .gif to find the time required for one frame (`frame_time`), rounding to the nearest even number since .gif frame times are only accurate up to whole milliseconds

  - `frame_time = MSPL / num_frames`
- Add up the total frame times (`actual_duration`) and loop through frames adding or subtracting 1 millisecond until `actual_duration` matches `ceil(MSPL)` (always prioritizing longer actual duration over shorter duration)

  > ```py
  > difference = MSPL - actual_duration
  > if not math.isclose(0, difference):
  >     # Add the difference and always prioritize longer duration compared to real duration value
  >     correction = int(math.ceil(difference))
  >     for i in range(0, abs(correction)):
  >         # Add/subtract corrections as necessary to get actual duration as close as possible to calculated duration
  >         frame_times[i % len(frame_times)] += math.copysign(1, correction)
  > ```

Now from this, the actual Milliseconds/Loop of the gif should always be equal to MSLP or greater than MSLP. However, when I save the .gif with the specified frame times, if the correction value is not 0 then the .gif always plays at a faster speed than expected. I have noticed that when using other services online that provide the same "sync gif to music" functionality, this is also the case; so it's not just me going crazy I think.

Below is the actual code used to get frame times:

```py
def get_frame_times(tempo: float, beats_per_loop: int, num_frames: int):
    # Calculate the number of seconds per beat in order to get number of milliseconds per loop
    beats_per_sec = tempo / 60
    secs_per_beat = 1 / beats_per_sec
    duration = math.ceil(secs_per_beat * beats_per_loop * 1000)
    frame_times = []
    # Try to make frame times as even as possible by dividing duration by number of frames and rounding
    actual_duration = 0
    for _ in range(0, num_frames):
        # Rounding method: Bankers Rounding (round to the nearest even number)
        frame_time = round(duration / num_frames)
        frame_times.append(frame_time)
        actual_duration += frame_time
    # Add the difference and always prioritize longer duration compared to real duration value
    difference = duration - actual_duration
    if not math.isclose(0, difference):
        correction = int(math.ceil(difference))
        for i in range(0, abs(correction)):
            # Add/subtract corrections as necessary to get actual duration as close as possible to calculated duration
            frame_times[i % len(frame_times)] += math.copysign(1, correction)
    return frame_times
```

I'm saving the gif by using PIL (Pillow)'s Image module:

```py
frame_times = get_frame_times(tempo, beats_per_loop, num_frames)
frames = []
for i in range(0, num_frames):
  # Frames are appended to frames list here
# disposal=2 used since the frames may be transparent
frames[0].save(
    output_file, 
    save_all=True, 
    append_images=frames[1:], 
    loop=0, 
    duration=frame_times, 
    disposal=2)
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here? I can't seem to find out why this isn't working and why the actual duration of the gif is much shorter than the specified frame times. It makes me feel slightly better that other sites/services that provide this functionality end up with the same results, but at the same time I feel like this should definitely be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I don't know if this is a limitation of the .gif format or if it's a limitation of the Image module in PIL, but it appears that frame times can only be accurate up to multiples of 10 milliseconds. Upon inspecting the actual frame times of the modified image, they were being floored to the nearest multiple of 10 resulting in an overall faster playback speed than expected.

To fix this, I modified the code to choose frame times in increments of 10 (again prioritizing a longer actual duration if necessary) and dispersing the frame time adjustments as evenly as possible throughout the list:

```py
def get_frame_times(tempo: float, beats_per_loop: int, num_frames: int):
    # Calculate the number of seconds per beat in order to get number of milliseconds per loop
    beats_per_sec = tempo / 60
    secs_per_beat = 1 / beats_per_sec
    duration = round_tens(secs_per_beat * beats_per_loop * 1000)
    frame_times = []
    # Try to make frame times as even as possible by dividing duration by number of frames
    actual_duration = 0
    for _ in range(0, num_frames):
        frame_time = round_tens(duration / num_frames)
        frame_times.append(frame_time)
        actual_duration += frame_time
    # Adjust frame times to match as closely as possible to the actual duration, rounded to multiple of 10
    # Keep track of which indexes we've added to already and attempt to split corrections as evenly as possible
    # throughout the frame times
    correction = duration - actual_duration
    adjust_val = int(math.copysign(10, correction))
    i = 0
    seen_i = {i}
    while actual_duration != duration:
        frame_times[i % num_frames] += adjust_val
        actual_duration += adjust_val
        if i not in seen_i:
            seen_i.add(i)
        elif len(seen_i) == num_frames:
            seen_i.clear()
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1
        i += num_frames // abs(correction // 10)
    return frame_times
```